# Can't run java validation (JSR 303)

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, conflict, bean-validation

Recently ,I decide to use JSR 303 to validate bean In our project,But when i run JUNI test,It got error,The log is as below:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1242)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:139)
    at com.icil.service.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:74)
    at com.icil.sofs.booking.model.ValidateTest.test1(ValidateTest.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Someone told me this is due to conflicting JAR files. But I don't know which JAR are conflicting. Could anybody could tell me which JAR files are conflicted. Any help is huge for me,Thanks!!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing similar problem. Actually, HibernatePersistence was not having ProviderUtil() method in entity jars.  following combination works well.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.5.6-Final</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>3.6.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

without list of JARs its quite hard to help you here.
Do you have maven in your project?

If so, you can use `mvn dependency:tree and see the tree of jars.

It can be that you're using hibernate that doesn't conform the JPA 2.0 Specification ProviderUtil class was introduced in JPA 2.0 as the doc states: 
[ProviderUtil](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil.html)

Yet another concern:
Are you running standalone or inside some container (app/web server or something)
If you're running a JBoss for example it has its own jars in the lib folder that can also clash with your jars. How exactly you're running your JUnit test?

Comment: Dear Mark:Thanks for your answer and Yes,We use Maven in our project,I didn't run the application in any container,Just in Junit.I have upload the screen-shot of my project's dependent JAR files ,Please see if you can find which JAR files is conflicted ,Thanks,

Comment: As far as I understand, jpa 2 final is supported by hibernate 3.5. The HibernatePersistence class comes with hibernate-entitymanager jar I didn't find it in the list you've provided. In any case the hibernate versions should be aligned : you use both 3.4.0 and 3.3.0 at least for annotations. Given you're not using any kind of container, I guess you should check the hibernate versions compatibility. This kind of problem is very specific to your environment, and it doesn't have 'general' solution... Maybe running mvn dependency:tree as I stated before will also provide you additional input

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a validation problem, consider using your own implementation of TraversableResolver instead of JPATraversableResolver or DefaultTraversableResolver.
[Here's how to do it](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-bootstrapping.html#d0e2255).

JPATraversableResolver might cause an unwished dependency to JPA. [Here's a guy with a similar problem.](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1005704)

Of course, if you expect your application to JPA2-compliant, this is not a solution.

```
public class MyTraversableResolver implements TraversableResolver {

     public boolean isReachable(Object traversableObject, Path.Node traversableProperty, Class rootBeanType, Path pathToTraversableObject, ElementType elementType) {
        return true;
     }

     public boolean isCascadable(Object traversableObject, Path.Node traversableProperty, Class rootBeanType, Path pathToTraversableObject, ElementType elementType) {
        return true;
     }
}
```