# AbstractMethodError in Spring Filter org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.

I have implemented a filter with this method:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
        ThreadContext threadContext;

        //String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();

        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            threadContext = ThreadContext.getInstance();

            try {

                DetailedUser ecasUser = (DetailedUser) httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();

                if (ecasUser != null) {
                    threadContext.setDomainUsername(ecasUser.getDomainUsername());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (httpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()!=null) {         
                threadContext.setUserID(httpServletRequest.getRemoteUser());
            }
        }


        try {

            if (filterChain != null) {

                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);                

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            LOGGER.equals(e.getMessage());
        }    
    }
```

In this line `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` I have this strange error:

```
] Root cause of ServletException.
ava.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;
       at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Persistence.java:110)
       at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:62)
       at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:94)
       at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
       at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isCascadeRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:783)
       at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:360)
       at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:216)
       at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
       at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:102)
       at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:772)
       at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:159)
       at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:107)
       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
       at com.tdk.devices.support.context.DevicesSecurityFilter.doFilter(DevicesSecurityFilter.java:82)
```

this are the libraries imported:

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <!-- <version>1.3</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.cec</groupId>
            <artifactId>databaseMessageSource</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
          <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.10</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai_codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2_01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai_core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>caja</groupId>
            <artifactId>json_simple</artifactId>
            <version>r1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <classifier>jdk13</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mlibwrapper_jai</groupId>
            <artifactId>mlibwrapper_jai</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>odmg</groupId>
            <artifactId>odmg</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>springext</groupId>
            <artifactId>springext</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0-spring3-2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-compat</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-jstlel</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.bytecode</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-tests-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>
```

It seems to be related to the **hibernate** dependencies of the pom.xml file

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23632603/4891892) may fix your issue

Comment: hope this will help [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237879/cant-run-java-validation-jsr-303)

Comment: it seems some classloading issue.Did you try to set class order in order to load classes from your web-app first and then from parent classloading?

Comment: I think multiple library version conflict of hibernate-entitymanager. Check with hibernate-entitymanager pom file and it's dependency libraries. best way to check in your system home folder \.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\3.3.2.GA\hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.2.GA.pom file

Comment: You are trying to mix Hibernate versions 5.2.2.Final and 3.something among the different dependencies, and that can't possibly work well. Stick to one version, and upgrade them together. Look at all these conflicts: `3.2.6.ga`, `3.3.1.GA`, `3.0.0.ga`, `3.3.2.GA`, `3.3.0.GA`, `5.2.2.Final`

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind this error is, Hibernate’s in build PersistenceProviderResolver returns the list of all PersistenceProviders on the classpath. Since Weblogic lib contains JPA 1.0, it returns JPA2.0 as well as JPA 1.0 persistence provider.

To fix this error, you can use following approach.

Create a class HibernatePersistenceProviderResolver as

```
 public class HibernatePersistenceProviderResolver implements PersistenceProviderResolver {

private volatile PersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = new HibernatePersistence();

public List getPersistenceProviders() {
return Collections.singletonList(persistenceProvider);
}

public void clearCachedProviders() {
persistenceProvider = new HibernatePersistence();
}

public static void register() {
PersistenceProviderResolverHolder
.setPersistenceProviderResolver(new HibernatePersistenceProviderResolver());
}
}
```

Add a listener class to call register method as

```
public class HibernateContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
HibernatePersistenceProviderResolver.register();

}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Add the entry of listener in your web.xml

Comment: Also add hibernate dependicies to ur pom.xml

Answer (score -1):

It Seems that doFilter() is abstract method and your code is calling it. When we call abstract method it throws AbstractMethodError for more info [here (docs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)